# XPathSelectElements Method yields no results?

Tags: c#, xpath, xmlreader

```
    string xml = @"<AllBands  >
    <Band>
      <Name ID=""1234"" started=""1962"">Beatles<![CDATA[lalala]]></Name>
      <Last>1</Last>
      <Salary>2</Salary>
    </Band>
    <Band>
      <Name ID=""222"" started=""1968"">Doors<![CDATA[lalala]]></Name>
      <Last>1</Last>
      <Salary>2</Salary>
    </Band>
  </AllBands>";



     XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
      XElement root = XElement.Load(reader);
     var child1 = root.XPathSelectElements(@"/AllBands/Band" );
```

child1 has no childs !

What am i missing ?

Comment: See [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx)

Comment: You should be [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) both `StringReader` and `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` does not refer to the XML document, it refers to the `AllBands` element since you loaded it using `XElement.Load()`.  So your XPATH should be relative to that element.

```
var children = root.XPathSelectElements("Band");
```